# Nuget Package Manager showing updates for packages not installed

Tags: nuget

When I go to update in Nuget it shows packages that arent installed anywhere in the project.  I do a search for say "SimpleJson", nothing in the project is referencing it.  How can I get rid of this from the update list?

Comment: Have you tried issuing the command `uninstall-package SimpleJson` ?

Comment: That worked.  I guess I should use the command line in these instances. If you make this an answer Ill make it answered.

Comment: I had this problem once too with EF. It was installed, but I could not reference the namespace. So I used a quick un/install from the packet manager console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the `Uninstall-package SimpleJson` command. It should delete any "ghost" references in your solution.